# What is the fastest way to regenerate life?

Tags: terraria

What is the fastest way to naturally regenerate HP?   I know for sure honey increases the rate of hp regen, and so do campfires.   I know for sure there are some other HP regenerating items such as Crimson Armor's Set Bonus as well as some accessories.

What's the fastest possible way to naturally regenerate HP without relying on potions?

Comment: standing still apparently causes you to regenerate 2x as fast as when moving. http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Health_Points

Comment: You COULD pay the nurse.  Lord knows she hardly gets to do anything anymore, the poor thing.

Comment: @Zibbobz Naturally regenerate, not bribe another to heal you >.<

Comment: Regeneration points are super easy to make and don't require you to faff about with campfires and honey. Why not use them?

Comment: @kotzekot I just want a setup I can use when I'm travelling in the Jungle, since I get hit by so many posion debuffs it's not even funny.  I'd love to be able to fight bosses without having to rely on hp potions as well.

Comment: Well, you're obviously not going to be able to use honey or campfires when traveling (unless you cover the entire jungle with them), and crimson armor is going to lose you health in the long run if you use it instead of higher tier armors.

Comment: Seems like what he's really looking for is the optimal loadout for health regen, and possibly the best conditions for recovering health rapidly when one needs to seek shelter and has no health potions.

Comment: I thought there was a weapon added in 1.2 that, besides delivering a lot of damage, also gives a portion of health to the player. I think they were called Vampire Knives. With these you can just run around and kill everything whilst taking 0 damage. So you'll practically immortal.

Comment: Right, but you're not passively regenerating HP if you stand still

Comment: @VascovdEng You are not even close to basically immortal. I use these vampire knives and I still get ripped apart if i don't pay attention to drink potions every now and then.

Comment: @Arperum Not if you got a high defense you won't.

Comment: @VascovdEng I'd assume that Oricalchum armor counts as "high defense". Immortal means that you can't die to anything, I can just stay there and kill pre-hardmode bosses, but having some hardmode jungle situation can still kill you. It happens less frequently, sure, but you can still die. 2 bouldertraps + 7 moss hornets + a couple of those things on vines will pretty much eat you.

Comment: @Arperum I know, I've been there, until I learned that I needed to be less offensive and more defensive. And those things on vines are called "Snatchers", "Man Eaters" and "Angry Trappers".

Comment: @VascovdEng I'm at work, cazn't look these things upo now, so therefor vine things. And in the more defensive then offensive case, that is at least 50-80% of your immortality.

Comment: @kotekzot With a HIve Wand you can have mini pools of honey wherever you wish, as long as you have the hive blocks.  That means that you can have honey pratically everywhere, it just depends on where you put it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these:

- Celestial stone = 2+ life regen
- Moon stone = 2+ life regen (at night)
- Moon charm = 0.5+ life regen (at night)
- Charm of myths = 0.5 life regen
- Band of regeneration = 0.5 life regen
- Palladium armor (warrior set) = major increase
- Fireplace = decent increase
- Heart lamp = decent increase
- Honey pool = good increase

I'd recommend to replace the charm of myths and the band of regeneration with a damage accessory or mobility accessory because they are both the weakest regen item in the game. Also, a lot of this only works at night making it perfect for bosses and night time events.

Comment: The v1.3 introduces an expert-only accessory that adds +10 life regen if standing still.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to wire a pressure plate to a heart statue, as they will produce hearts on a ten second cooldown, if you are looking for better ways to manage health in the field - boss fights and the like.

The wiki page explains it a bit better than I can, but if you set up remote health stations like this up around the world then all you have to do is run to the nearest health station. Similarly, if you struggle with mana, you can do the same thing with star statues.

Answer (score 3):

Stand in Honey that is close to a CampFire while wearing Crimson armour. You will generate health about 350-400% faster than normal. If you actually had a regen potion, it would, of course, be even faster. You could possibly recover 449 health in as little as 30 seconds. I've seen it happen. I have regeneration pools all over my server for boss battles and such. A band of regeneration and a charm of myths would help even more!

Comment: As of 1.2.1.2, standing near a [Heart Lantern](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Lantern) will also increase your life regen.

Answer (score 2):

I had a setup for a faster health regen in a pumpkin moon.

The easiest way to regen health is to place 2 heart lanterns and campfires around, while standing in a pool of honey with neptune's shell equipped.
Spectre armour works well for casters, it only regenerates with magic items. I already tried using vampire knives but it didn't work.
Use greater healing potions and regen potions.

These accessories should be also worn :

- celestial stone
- charm of myths
- moon stone
- moon charm
- star veil/holy cross neckalace

All of this could be an amazing setup for boss fights.

P.s. (I would use a heart statue and connect it to a 1 second timer to regain health back even faster.)

Answer (score 1):

you can also get a heart crystal and chains to make a heart lantern which also increases health regen

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, as of 1.3, killing golem in expert mode will drop a treasure bag containing the [shiny stone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shiny_Stone). This increases the health regen massively when not moving (starting at 10 health per second, and increasing until it gets to around 40 health per second).